# Is the $B$-field gradient the reason why iron is moved into the center of a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was wondering how to calculate the pull force of an iron rod into the center of a solenoid correctly (dependent on it's position) and whether the rod would also move towards the center of an ideal solenoid (infinite length), or whether this effect is only present if there is a field gradient (finite lenght).

Would it make sense to estimate at each time step the difference in field density within the solenoid and use the difference to estimate the pull force at each time point? Is the rod always magnetized evenly, are there approximations?

[image]

Comment: What is shown in the picture?

Comment: It shows B in a coil....

Comment: $\vec {B}$ is a vector, and the picture shows a scalar. What is it?

Comment: probably the length of the vector at a position in tesla. its from wikipedia.. Otherwise I am not sure what else it could be :) They want to show the field density in a solenoid. There anyway the direction is all equal (more or less)

Comment: Do you want to calculate the force that acts on the iron rod in the solenoid field? Do you need a code or theory?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I think both would be fine but code is preferred :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we calculate the solenoid field without artifacts shown on https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zylinderspule . To do this, take into account the final diameter of the wire wound on. Then the artifacts disappear and the field looks like this
[image: Figure 1]
The force acting on a magnetizing projectile is defined as $\vec {F}=\nabla (\vec {m}.\vec {B})$,where $\vec {m}$ is the magnetic moment. We will consider two cases:

1. $\vec {m}=k\vec {B}$,where $k$ depends on the shape and magnetic properties of the projectile. Then the force distribution in half of the solenoid at $k=1$ is shown in Fig. 2 on the left, and the force plots for $r=0.0001,0.1,0.25$ are shown on the right from top to bottom, respectively.
   [image: Figure 2]
2. $m=const$ - permanent magnet. Then the force distribution in half of the solenoid at $\vec {m}=(0,0,1)$ is shown in Fig. 3 on the left, and the force plots for $r=0.0001,0.1,0.25$ are shown on the right from top to bottom, respectively.
   [image: Figure 3]